# Change list from vertical to horizontal possible through CSS?

Tags: php, css

Im using mrbs (https://sourceforge.net/projects/mrbs/) for our discussion rooms booking. By defaults, mrbs allow list room vertically or select option using drop down menu. Is it possible to modified the week and month php page so that room will be list horizontally to the right?

When using vertical list, there's too much empty space marked with red color below..

[image]

Something like this?

[image]

```html
<div class="contents">
<div id="dwm_header" class="screenonly">
<div id="dwm_rooms">
<h3>Rooms</h3><ul>
<li><a href="week.php?year=2019&amp;month=10&amp;day=14&amp;area=5&amp;room=5"><span class="current">Room 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="week.php?year=2019&amp;month=10&amp;day=14&amp;area=5&amp;room=6"><span>Room 2</span></a></li>
<li><a href="week.php?year=2019&amp;month=10&amp;day=14&amp;area=5&amp;room=7"><span>Room 3</span></a></li>
<li><a href="week.php?year=2019&amp;month=10&amp;day=14&amp;area=5&amp;room=8"><span>Room 4</span></a></li>
<li><a href="week.php?year=2019&amp;month=10&amp;day=14&amp;area=5&amp;room=9"><span>Room 5</span></a></li>
<li><a href="week.php?year=2019&amp;month=10&amp;day=14&amp;area=5&amp;room=10"><span>Room 6</span></a></li>
<li><a href="week.php?year=2019&amp;month=10&amp;day=14&amp;area=5&amp;room=11"><span>Room 7</span></a></li>
<li><a href="week.php?year=2019&amp;month=10&amp;day=14&amp;area=5&amp;room=17"><span>Smart Room</span></a></li>
<li><a href="week.php?year=2019&amp;month=10&amp;day=14&amp;area=5&amp;room=18"><span>AV Room</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, the code is not obfuscated. Find the element, change the code.

Comment: thank you for your reply, could you guide me what is the fuction or any link for my reference? I have zero on php. Just start learning this to install mrbs for our library..

Comment: if you are not able to find the files, I'll take a look at it for you, is this project available online on github, so i don't have to go download it locally ?

Comment: remove the `\n` as it is used for line breaks `echo "<div id=\"dwm\">";
echo "<h2>" . htmlspecialchars("$this_area_name - $this_room_name") . "</h2>, ";
echo "</div>";`

Comment: @OmarAbbas hi, i just literally learned and uploaded my project to github. Please check it out. https://github.com/amein14/roombooking. Not sure how to use it either, is it correct way?

Comment: I'll have a look at it.

Comment: what is the link that shows the above screenshot that you posted in the question ?

Comment: that screenshot taken from week view and the link `/roombooking/web/week.php?year=2019&month=10&day=12&area=5&room=8` month view `/roombooking/web/month.php?year=2019&month=10&day=12&area=5&room=8`

Comment: can you also take the screenshot of the inspect element of the above screen in your question ?

Comment: here https://i.imgur.com/q3NgYX4.png

Comment: `make_room_select_html(` this is the function that creates the view you want to change, and it is located in this page `https://github.com/amein14/roombooking/blob/master/web/functions.inc`

Comment: @are you able to fix it like you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** Code not tested. if it does not work properly, you might need to tweak a little.

Go to the file (roombooking/web/functions.inc) and replace the function `function make_room_select_html (` with the following code.)

```
function make_room_select_html ($link, $area, $current, $year, $month, $day)
{
  global $area_list_format;

  $out_html = '';
  $rooms = get_room_names($area);

  // Only show the rooms if there's more than one of them, otherwise
  // there's no point
  if (count($rooms) > 1)
  {
    $custom_styles = "<style>
    #dwm_rooms ul {
      list-style-type: none !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      overflow: hidden !important;
    }

    #dwm_rooms li {
      float: left !important;
      background-color: #333333 !important;
      margin-left: 4px !important;
    }

    #dwm_rooms li a {
      display: block !important;
      color: white !important;
      text-align: center !important;
      padding: 4px !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
    }
    </style>";

    $out_html .= "<div id=\"dwm_rooms\">\n";
    $out_html .= "<h3>" . get_vocab("rooms") . "</h3>";
    if ($area_list_format == "select")
    {
      $form = new Form();

      $form->setAttributes(array('id'     => 'roomChangeForm',
                                 'method' => 'get',
                                 'action' => $link));

      $form->addHiddenInputs(array('page_date' => format_iso_date($year, $month, $day),
                                   'area'      => $area));

      $select = new ElementSelect();
      $select->setAttributes(array('class'    => 'room_area_select',
                                   'id'       => 'room_select',
                                   'name'     => 'room',
                                   'onchange' => 'this.form.submit()'))
             ->addSelectOptions($rooms, $current, true);
      $form->addElement($select);

      // Note:  the submit button will not be displayed if JavaScript is enabled
      $submit = new ElementInputSubmit();
      $submit->setAttributes(array('class' => 'js_none',
                                   'value' => get_vocab('change')));
      $form->addElement($submit);

      $out_html .= $form->toHTML();
    }
    else  // list format
    {
      $out_html .= "<ul>\n";
      foreach ($rooms as $room_id => $room_name)
      {
        $out_html .= "<li><a href=\"$link?year=$year&amp;month=$month&amp;day=$day&amp;area=$area&amp;room=" . $room_id . "\">";
        $out_html .= "<span" . (($room_id == $current) ? ' class="current"' : '') . ">";
        $out_html .= htmlspecialchars($room_name) . "</span></a></li>\n";
      }
      $out_html .= "</ul>\n";
    }
    $out_html .= "</div>\n";
  }
  return $out_html;
} // end make_room_select_html
```

Comment: Hi, I have replaced this function but nothing change. I will check/tweak on Monday. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: put something extra as an attribute in that function in `<h3>` and see if that displays in the inspect element.

Answer (score 1):

Found out this css works too

```
li {
display: inline-block;
}
```